# Negative look ahead regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

How can I match strings that aren't preceded by an `@` sign?

```
/(?!@)(somestring|someotherstring)/
```

Doesn't produce expected results. Am testing this in sublime text following [Sublime: Regular Expressions.cheatsheet](https://github.com/dmikalova/sublime-cheat-sheets/blob/master/cheat-sheets/Regular%20Expressions.cheatsheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a *lookbehind*:

```
(?<!@)(somestring|someotherstring)
```

The `(?!@)` lookahead will check if the *following* symbol is not a `@`.

Some [more details](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> **Lookbehind** has the same effect [*VS*: as *lookahead*], but **works backwards**. It tells the regex engine to temporarily step backwards in the string, to check if the text inside the lookbehind can be matched there. `(?<!a)b` matches a `b` that is not preceded by an `a`, using **negative lookbehind**. It doesn't match `cab`, but matches the `b` (and only the `b`) in `bed` or `debt`.
>
> Negative lookbehind is written as `(?<!text)`, using an exclamation point instead of an equals sign.

Comment: I have another similar question, my regex looks like this `^(\s*)USE (\[?)(?<![master|\$])(.)+(\]?)` - should I post a new question for it?

Comment: Yes, it should be a new question. I see too many issues in it. Do not forget to describe what is wrong with it, and some input sample string and expected output. Do not ask to explain you the meaning of the regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926951/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-match-for-sql-script