# Regex lookahead/lookbehind match for SQL script

Tags: regex, t-sql, sublimetext2, sqlcmd

I'm trying to analyse some SQLCMD scripts for code quality tests. I have a regex not working as expected:

```
^(\s*)USE (\[?)(?<![master|\$])(.)+(\]?)
```

I'm trying to match:

1. Strings that start with USE (ignore whitespace)
2. Followed by optional square bracket
3. Followed by 1 or more non-whitespace characters.
4. EXCEPT where that text is "master" (case insensitive)
5. OR EXCEPT where that that text is a `$` symbol

Expected results:

`USE [master]` - don't match

`USE [$(CompiledDatabaseName)]` - don't match

`USE [anything_else.01234]` - match

Also, the same patterns above without the `[` and `]` characters.

I'm using Sublime Text 2 as my RegEx search tool and referencing this [cheatsheet](https://github.com/dmikalova/sublime-cheat-sheets/blob/master/cheat-sheets/Regular%20Expressions.cheatsheet)

Comment: What is *alpha text*?

Comment: I edited correction with the correct meaning

Comment: Can there be nested `[...]`?

Comment: No: only `USE somestring` or `USE [somestring]` not `USE [[somestring]]`

Comment: Try `^(?!\h*USE\h*\[{0,2}[^]\s]*(?:\$|(?i:master)))\h*USE\h*\[{0,2}[^]\s]*]{0,2}`. `\h` stands for a horizontal whitespace, but you may switch to `\s` if you need to match newlines. A shortened version: [`^\h*USE(?!\h*\[{0,2}[^]\s]*(?:\$|(?i:master)))\h*\[{0,2}[^]\s]*]{0,2}`](https://regex101.com/r/aB1jD4/2)

Comment: AWESOME! I tip my hat to you, sir! Please can you add as answer so I can mark correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern  - `^(\s*)USE (\[?)(?<![master|\$])(.)+(\]?)` - uses a lookbehind that is variable-width (its length is not known beforehand) if you fix the character class issue inside it (i.e. replace `[...]` with `(...)` as you mean an alternative list of `$` or a character sequence `master`) and thus is invalid in a Boost regex. Your `(.)+` capturing is wrong since this group will only contain one last character captured (you could use `(.+)`), but this also matches spaces (while you need *1 or more non-whitespace characters*). `?` is the *one or zero times* quantifier, but you say you might have 2 opening and closing brackets (so, you need a limiting quantifier `{0,2}`).

You can use

```
^\h*USE(?!\h*\[{0,2}[^]\s]*(?:\$|(?i:master)))\h*\[{0,2}[^]\s]*]{0,2}
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aB1jD4/2)

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of a line in Sublime Text
- `\h*` - optional horizontal whitespace (if you need to match newlines, use `\s*`)
- `USE` - a literal case-sensitive character sequence `USE`
- `(?!\h*\[{0,2}[^]\s]*(?:\$|(?i:master)))` - a negative lookahead that makes sure the `USE` is NOT followed with:

  - `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace
  - `\[{0,2}` - zero, one or two `[` brackets
  - `[^]\s]*` - zero or more characters other than `]` and whitespace
  - `(?:\$|(?i:master))` - either a `$` or a case-insensitive `master` (we turn off case sensitivity with `(?i:...)` construct)
- `\h*` - go on matching zero or more horizontal whitespace
- `\[{0,2}` - zero, one or two `[` brackets
- `[^]\s]*` - zero or more characters other than `]` and whitespace (when `]` is the first character in a character class, it does not have to be escaped in Boost/PCRE regexps)
- `]{0,2}` - zero, one or two `]` brackets (outside of character class, the closing square bracket does not need escaping)

Comment: Please check the explanation and if there is anything unclear please ask. I also commented on your pattern.

Comment: Actually, there should only be zero or one `[` brackets

Comment: One or zero = `?` quantifier.